# How to make the relationship between selects

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 selekta, they have option parameters. I want that when I click on "Black White Pink Red Gray", "1 2 3", "A B C" parameters of the first select, the second select will change accordingly to "$ 10", "20", "30".

```
function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        value={category}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
          setCategory(value);
        }}
      >
        <option>{"Black"}</option>
        <option>{"White"}</option>
        <option>{"Pink"}</option>
        <option>{"Red"}</option>
        <option>{"Gray"}</option>
        <option>{"1"}</option>
        <option>{"2"}</option>
        <option>{"3"}</option>
        <option>{"A"}</option>
        <option>{"B"}</option>
        <option>{"C"}</option>
      </select>

      <select
        value={?}
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
          //?
        }}
      >
        <option>{"$10"}</option>
        <option>{"$20"}</option>
        <option>{"$30"}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But if the second one can only be one of the three prices, does it make sense to have a drop down there? What happens if the user picks the price first, you cannot really distinguish what it should be in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new state variable for the price:

```js
const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
```

and inside your onChange handler for the category you can call `setPrice` inside an if statement.

```
  if (value === "Red") {
     setPrice("$30");
  }
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qqv4rm71xj) (click on red in the first select)